# Android / Koin - Dynamically load data modules for features

Tags: android, dynamic, module, android-jetpack, koin

I have many different feature modules and for each of them I've created a domain and data module. Here's my structure.

feature-a

- feature_a_domain
- feature_a_data
- feature_a_ui

feature-b

- feature_b_domain
- feature_b_data
- feature_b_ui

Each feature is a folder containing these three projects. Domain is pure kotlin, data depends on domain, and UI depends on domain interfaces while my app module injects data.

In some cases, feature_b might want to access data from the domain of feature_a. For example, I might do this in the feature_b_ui gradle:

```
implementation project ("feature_a:feature_a_domain")
```

I have got this building and launching. My main problem now has to do with dynamically loading the data modules I need with Koin for a particular feature.

If feature needs to dynamically load a data module, I have to reference the data module in the activity. This means that my feature_a_ui project needs to reference the data project as a dependency as so.

```
implementation project(':feature_a:feature_a_data')
```

I can then do this and bootstrap my dependencies for the dynamic feature.

```html
class FeatureAActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    val model: FeatureAViewModel by viewModel()

    private val loadFeatures by lazy {   loadKoinModules(listOf(featureAModule, featureBDataModule))     }

    private fun injectFeatures() = loadFeatures

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feature_a)
        loadKoinModules(listOf(featureAModule, featureBDataModule))
       }
       
     override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unloadKoinModules(listOf(featureAModule, featureBDataModule))
    }
}
```

I'm not OK with this because I don't want my feature activity to know where it's data is coming from. I feel like I need some other module that's like an injector which binds all of this together but I can't do that in the app project because these feature modules and their data modules are dynamically loaded and delivered to the app.

Does anyone recommend a way that I can move this module loading outside of my feature activities ? This code seems against clean architecture.

Thank you :)

Comment: Any ideas ? Still need a solution.